# Renaming blank first column and getting x axis labels right while plotting using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot temp Vs time graph using pandas. CSV file I am importing from is tab delimited. After reading the CSV into the dataframe, (as shown below) first column in it is date and time. There is no name for that column. I tried renaming the column but it looks impossible.

Also when I plot the graph temp vs time, there is nothing mentioned on x axis but some ticks. Need help with this as well.

My dataframe looks like this, as you can see first column is datetime, should have had column name as time, but it is blank!

```
                     reactorPressure   vacuumGauge   MFC1   MFC2 ...    rfFreq   crucTemp   vacPressure   \r
                                                                 ...                                        
2018-12-18 10:18:18             0.05  4.569000e-07   -0.4    0.0 ...    11.496      503.0                 \r
2018-12-18 10:18:28             0.12  4.616000e-07   -0.4    0.0 ...    11.481      509.0                 \r
2018-12-18 10:18:38             0.25  4.584000e-07   -0.4    0.0 ...    11.475      514.0                 \r
2018-12-18 10:18:48             0.20  4.622000e-07   -0.4    0.0 ...    11.481      519.0                 \r
2018-12-18 10:18:58             0.25  4.641000e-07   -0.4    0.0 ...    11.484      524.0                 \r

[5 rows x 12 columns]
Index(['reactorPressure', ' vacuumGauge', ' MFC1', ' MFC2', ' MFC3',
       ' rfVoltage', ' rfCurrent', ' rfPower', ' rfFreq', ' crucTemp',
       ' vacPressure', ' \r'],
      dtype='object')
```

To solve the renaming issue, I tried

```
df.rename(columns={'':'Time'}, inplace=True)
```

, but did not work, I don't see a Unnamed :0 when I run #print(df.head() command.

I tried

```
df.columns=['Time'] + df.columns.tolist()[1:]
print(df.columns)
```

, but this instead of adding name to column zero, it renames column 1.

I tried deleting the columns and then adding them manually with

```
df.read_csv('filename.csv',names=['Time', 'pressure',..])
```

did not work either. It always leaves first column blank. 
My code is below!

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('testfile3.csv',sep='\t',lineterminator='\n', index_col=0)
print(df.head())
df[' crucTemp'].plot()
plt.show()
```

Appreciate your kind help! THanks! I can also share my csv file here, but I don't know how. I can email you this file if you leave your email address, or I can upload the file if you tell me how!

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpKgs.png][1]

Link for the plot crucTemp Vs (first column date and time), has no numbers on x axis. I honestly don't care about the dataframe not having name for first column, but I need x axis to be printed with proper numbers.

Comment: 1. There is no image link. 2. Don't post data, code or anything like this as an image (link), but do post it as code indented, copy/pastable text. Thank you. In this case just post the first few lines of your csv file, so that people can directly see what you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything's fine there. The first "headless" column is your index, often simply a counter column, but you explicitely set the first data column as index by writing `index_col=0` in your data import command `pd.read_csv()`.

However, the type of this index is still string, so pandas (or matplotlib under the hood) doesn't know about the timing nature of this index.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

should help.

Comment: @SpghttdCd thank you, It took me a day to realize this. It works now fine!